# Override category H1 with custom attribute - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, custom-field

I would like to create a new field for category pages which I can use to override the default H1 on front-end.

Currently if have a category called '**Stuff**', my breadcrumb is '**Stuff**' and my H1 is '**Stuff**'.

What I want is a category called '**Stuff**', breadcrumb '**Stuff**', and H1 '**Magnificent Stuff at Great Prices!**'.

So I believe I need a way to do the following:

1. Create new 'Custom H1' field on Category pages in back-end
2. If 'Custom H1' field not empty, replace default H1 with 'Custom H1'

I found this article, but it's for Magento 1. I need a M2 solution of this: https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2014/06/create-custom-category-attribute-to-override-category-h1-in-magento/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to add custom H1 and an optional H2.

Tested with Magento 2.3.

Note: Replace `HeavyDots` with your own vendor name if you'd like.

### Create new module

Create module under `app\code\HeavyDots\SeoAddHeadingsToCategory`

#### Registration

Create `app\code\HeavyDots\SeoAddHeadingsToCategory\registration.php` with the following:

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'HeavyDots_SeoAddHeadingsToCategory',
    __DIR__
);
```

#### Create module.xml

Create `app\code\HeavyDots\SeoAddHeadingsToCategory\etc\module.xml` with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="HeavyDots_SeoAddHeadingsToCategory" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence></sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

#### Create the script that will add the new fields to DB

Create `app\code\HeavyDots\SeoAddHeadingsToCategory\Setup\InstallData.php` with:

```
<?php

// https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html

namespace HeavyDots\SeoAddHeadingsToCategory\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
    ModuleContextInterface,
    ModuleDataSetupInterface,
    InstallDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'custom_heading_one', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom H1',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => 'store',
            'group' => 'Search Engine Optimization',
            'required' => false
        ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'custom_heading_two', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom H2',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => 'store',
            'group' => 'Search Engine Optimization',
            'required' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### Create xml config so fields will show up on category form

Create `app\code\HeavyDots\SeoAddHeadingsToCategory\view\adminhtml\ui_component\category_form.xml` with:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="search_engine_optimization">
        
        <field name="custom_heading_one" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Custom H1</label>
                <dataScope>custom_heading_one</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="custom_heading_two" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Custom H2</label>
                <dataScope>custom_heading_two</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

#### Upload and enable the new module

Push your code to the server and run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

#### Now you should be able to see the fields in category form under

Go to `Catalog > Categories` > Select and edit one, and open the `Search Engine Optimization` section.

[image: magento 2 custom category h1 and h2]

Now to display it on the frontend category page..

#### Override the default page title html view

Create `app\code\HeavyDots\SeoAddHeadingsToCategory\view\frontend\templates\title.phtml` with:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

$catalogHelperData = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data');
$categoryObject = $catalogHelperData->getCategory();

if ($categoryObject) {
  $categoryCustomHeadingOne = trim($categoryObject->getCustomHeadingOne());
  $categoryCustomHeadingTwo = trim($categoryObject->getCustomHeadingTwo());
}

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$titleHtml = '';
$pageHeading=trim($block->getPageHeading());
if (isset($categoryCustomHeadingOne) && !empty($categoryCustomHeadingOne)) {
  $pageHeading = $categoryCustomHeadingOne;
}
if ($pageHeading) {
    $titleHtml = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" '
        . $block->getAddBaseAttribute()
        . '>'
        . $block->escapeHtml($pageHeading)
        . '</span>';
}
?>
<?php if ($titleHtml) : ?>
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($cssClass) ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()) : ?> id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getId()) ?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()) : ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()) ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $titleHtml ?>
    </h1>
    <?php if (isset($categoryCustomHeadingTwo) && !empty($categoryCustomHeadingTwo)): ?>
    <h2 class="page-subtitle">
      <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($categoryCustomHeadingTwo); ?>
    </h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note: This file has been copied from: `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\title.phtml` and then modified.

You might want to copy it from there fresh and adapt it, in case your Magento version had changes.

#### Tell your category page to use the new title view

You must locate the `catalog_category_view.xml` in your theme file, and if you don't have it, create one.

In my case I had this file already:

`app\design\frontend\bs_rubix\bs_rubix1\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml`

Then edit the file and add the `<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">` with the `setTemplate` to make the block use the template file from your module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <!-- title block override start -->
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">HeavyDots_SeoAddHeadingsToCategory::title.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
      <!-- title block override end -->
    </body>
</page>
```

### Final thoughts

This is one way to accomplish it. Probably there could be better ways if you have more in depth knowledge of Magento customization.